# Symfony : multiple mercure subscriptions

Tags: symfony, turbo, mercure

I've developed an app based on this tutorial : https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/turbo

By the way, my app is broadcasting HTML updates on several topics, ie : chat-messages, notifications, chat-channels

So, every pages of my app is subscribing to these topics, and everything works beautifully on a local server, but as soon as I'm deploying this app online, every ajax calls are taking very much time, and the app is stucked.

When I'm disabling the mercure "subscribing" part, everything is working perfectly, but I really don't understand why...

Here is my setup :

- Debian 11 VPS
- PHP8.1
- Mercure 0.14.2
- Nginx with a reverse proxy configured on the mercure hub

I've tried to configure apache instead of nginx, but I've got the same problem

Comment: You must use HTTP 2, Mercure benefits from the HTTP/2 multiplexing mechanism. Configure your webserver to take HTTP2 into account (it works over SSL). Otherwise you will see the communication with the hub degraded, only 6 requests per browser.

Comment: You rock ! It works perfectly well after enabling HTTP/2 !